# jquerymobile datebox - How to call a function when date selected

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox

I have inherited some code using the jquerymobile datebox. The code so far concentrates on making the application look correct. I need to make it work so that when a date is selected, the server is called with the date and a new page loaded. Most examples just change the date in the page.

The code so far is :-

```js
$('#daycal').live('click', function() {
  $('#catchdate').datebox('open');
});

$( "#catchdate" ).bind( "change", function(event, ui) {
  $("#test1").val("xyz");
});
```

And

```html
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="catchdate">Some Date</label>
  <input name="catchdate" type="date" data-role="datebox" id="catchdate" data-options='{"mode":"calbox", "useNewStyle":true, "theme":true, "themeHeader":"f", "themeDateHigh":"f", "themeDatePick":"e", "themeDate":"f", "centerHoriz":true}' />
  <input id="test1" type="text"/> <!-- Later changed to a function call -->
</div>
```

In my simple test I expected the text in the input to change when a date was selected.

I have seen an example using the bind to change event, but I cannot get it to work. In the example I was just changing the value in an input element, later this will be changed to a function call.

I also saw somewhere in my search for an answer, a comment that 'live' was deprecated.

Finally, I thought I could use closeCallback ('Callbacks ('openCallback' and 'closeCallback') are simple to work with...') but could not find any examples of how it should be used.

What changes do I need to make to obtain the functionality I need?

Comment: There is no reason watching for the input to 'change' shouldn't work - although .live() or .on() are your friend - DateBox moves the input around, not sure if the .bind() is being unbound (it is possible).

Comment: That said, Sheetal's answer is quite correct.

Comment: I omitted to show that the click event is on an icon, not the input boc.

Comment: I used <input name="catchdate" onchange="datechanged(this)" etc.

Answer (score 5):

You could try using the close function of the date box, so that when user changes the date selection he makes and closes the date box you can call the server method with the selected date:

```
$('#DateSelectorId').bind('datebox', function (e, passed) { 
    if ( passed.method === 'close' ) {  
        // selected date
        var date = $('#DateSelectorId').val();          
        // make your service method and change page to another page
    }
});
```

Comment: I am sure your answer is good, but although I didn't include it in the code (! my mistake) the click event is on an icon, not on the input element. In any case thank you for the example I will use it elsewhere.

Comment: Now, one can check for passed.method === 'set' to see  if a date has been selected.  A user clicking the X icon will call 'close' method, even though a date is not being selected.

Answer (score 0):

think this can fix it

```
$('#catchdate').on('datebox', function(e, p) {
   if ( p.method === 'close' ) {
       alert('DO SOMETHING');
   }
});
```

u can go and test it on **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waamit14/ktbcP/13/)**

**i think u need some validation check for input box empty or not

Comment: And how this answer differs to the first one?

Comment: what if i just close the date-box or focus lost from date-box then also it will fire close event so u need to put some validation before and by the way sorry for that .

Comment: I checked out the code at Fiddle and then downloaded the source code adding the script to the html, but I couldn't get it to work. My inexperience I think as there was no icon on the input box that I could click. But thank you for the example.

Comment: u can do something like this=> bind input field click event and on that event put code for date-box open "$('#catchdate').datebox('open');"