# How to "onClick" on a date from JQM date-box

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am trying to get that date a user picked. The code is using jqm's datebox. Reading through jqm's demos and documentation doesn't seems touch on this scenario. I just want to get the date the user picked, check if its a weekend or not, then do stuff. I tried a few things I found via google by others, none helped. IT would be a great help if someone knew of some documentation or could show me a simple example to get onClick alert/console out the date of user's choice from datebox.

Update of my code below:

```
    $("#deliveryDate").on( "change",  function() {
    console.log("click, we in");
    console.log(document.getElementById("deliveryDate").value);
    console.log($(this).val());
    });

<div data-role="fieldcontain" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">      <label for="deliveryDate">Delivery Date:</label>
        <input id="deliveryDate" name="deliveryDate" type="date" data-role="datebox" value=""
         data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "useInline": true, "centerHoriz": true, "afterToday": true, "maxDays": 60}'/>mm/dd/yyyy</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that the id of the datebox is mode2 as shown.

```
<input name="mode2" class="form-control" id="mode2" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options="{&quot;mode&quot;:&quot;datebox&quot;}" readonly="readonly">
```

When you want to get the date just use

```
$("#mode2").on("change",function(){
    //straight js
    console.log(document.getElementById("mode2").value);
    //jquery
    console.log($(this).val())
});
```

Comment: I tried this before it did not work but tried again anyways cause maybe I messed up somewhere, still no dice :/ no errors in console nor do i get messages in console. Added my code above in case you might see something i overlooked

Comment: I also have tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719928/jquerymobile-datebox-how-to-call-a-function-when-date-selected no luck

Comment: Okay..... adding this code as a separate <script> tag under all my front end code worked